# Git ignore all files in directory but not directory

Tags: git

Now I was added in .gitignore

```
image/cache/*
```

Now git ignore all cache directory and I can't add this directory to git. Question is how to ignor image/cache/ files but, not directory ?

Comment: Use the file extention to ignore, otherwise, you can't do it

Comment: AFAIK you cannot. Git ignores empty directories. I've seen projects where a file was created only to make sure that git will create the parent folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the previous answer is pretty correct, this might be helpful:

You can specify a subdirectory of an ignored directory to not be ignored. eg:
Ignore cache, but not 'excluded' in cache:

```
!image/cache
images/cache/*
!images/cache/excluded
```

You can also force add ignored files using:

```
git add path/to/file --force
```

But as previously stated, this only works on files, not directories.

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned, git tracks files, git **does not** track folders.

If you put test.txt in a folder, git will "add" that folder only because it's part of the path that leads to test.txt.

Hence, if you ignore all files in a folder, git does nothing with the folder itself and it will not be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

One of solution is add to directory empty file `.gitkeep`